# How can I totally delete a user from Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: user-profile, user-accounts

I can delete a user from a site collection, but I can't seem to delete a user totally from SharePoint.

For example:

Let's say DOMAIN\joetest has a user ID of 15.  I can delete that account from the site collection (via web gui or powershell), but the next time that account is ensured the ID is still 15.

Is there a way to totally delete a user from SharePoint?  So, the next time the account is ensured it has a new ID (say 150 instead of 15).

Is that even possible.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the user from AD 
/Colin

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you need to do this?

I've often found remains of User Accounts in the User Profile/Social databases that tends to bring back some User information if I have lost a User from the main databases we use (it's a custom solution).

Answer (score 0):

This might be the intended behavior for cases where the users in no lnoger in the organization but its desire to have the metadata of created by and modified by where that users info is retained.

If all traces of the user is remove, would that not effect the metadata? Would versioning integrity still remain in tact? Not a hundred percent sure myself.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the user would have been a temporary solution to a larger issue with code.  Essentially could I find a temp fix so that my larger issue could be fixed in a proper manner.

The permanent solution to my issue was to recode a Timer Job.  It didn't take long, and deleting the user became a non-issue.

in all I could not find a way to delete a user from the sharepoint user list.  No matter how you delete the user from the site collection the user still remained in the user list.